# Finding a string by looping through an array php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, strpos

I have this array $filelist

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => .DS_Store [3] => 11-96.eml [4] => 11-97.eml )
```

Which is a list of all files in a particular directory... Sometimes there is no .DS_Store file, sometimes there is, sometimes there are 2 eml files, sometimes there are as many as 6. I'm trying to loop through and find the first array position a .eml file exists so that I can work out how many file are eml and where to start referencing the array.. I have tried...

```
 function firstFileInList($filelist) {
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($filelist as $value) {
          if(strpos($filelist, ".eml") == false) {
              $x = $x + 1;   
             //break;
            }

          }

          return $x;
      }
```

This returns 5, if I include the break it returns 1 and I was expecting to get 4.

Please could somebody point me in the right direction or even if there is a completely better way to do this then I would be more than grateful to see that...

Thanks Paul,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is what is the best way to find the location of a particular string in an Array, apologies...

Comment: consider `foreach (glob("/some/path/*.eml") as $filename){ ... }` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `break` exists every PHP loop directly when it is called, even if there are other elements. Use `continue` to get to the next element.

Based on your question

> I'm trying to loop through and find the first array position a .eml file exists

```
function firstFileInList($filelist) {
    foreach($filelist as $k => $v)
      if(strpos($v, ".eml") !== false)
        return $k;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend returning false at the end, in the case of no matches

Comment: @PaulLeppard: Perfect :-) You can mark the answer as solution later :-)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to grab a key from an array in a foreach is to define the key before it starts. Try updating your code with this:

```
function firstFileInList($filelist) {
    $x = false;
    foreach ($filelist as $key => $value) {
        if(strpos($value, ".eml") == false) {
            $x = $key;   
            break;
        }
    }
    return $x;
}
```

What this does is set $x to the actual key instead of a number that you increment like you would in a for() loop. $key will always be the array key, so in this example 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: Careful with this. If there is no match, it will return 0, suggesting a match was found in the first value. Perhaps define $x as false initially.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function firstFileInList($filelist) {
 $key=false;
    foreach ($filelist as $key=>$value) {
      if(strpos($value, ".eml") !==false){ 
         break;
        }
      }
      return $key; 
  }
```

In case there is no match you get false.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
 foreach ($filelist as $value) {
     if(strpos($filelist, ".eml") == false) {
```

Note that, for the foreach loop as you have written, it takes each element of the `$filelist` array, and puts it into the `$value` variable. Maybe you don't have warnings turned on in PHP, but when I tried your code, I got the following:

```
Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in test/a.php on line 6
```

What you want is

```
foreach ($filelist as $value) {
    if(strpos($value, ".eml") == false) {
        $x = $x + 1;
    }           
}
```

Note `$value` in the second line.